# How to deserialize a JSON file which contains null values using Serde?

Tags: json, rust, serde

I want to deserialize the chemical elements JSON file from [Bowserinator on github](https://github.com/Bowserinator/Periodic-Table-JSON/blob/master/PeriodicTableJSON.json) using Serde. For this I created a structure with all the needed fields and derived the needed macros:

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug, Clone)]
pub struct Element {
    name: String,
    appearance: String,
    atomic_mass: f64,
    boil: f64, 
    category: String,
    #[serde(default)]
    color: String,
    density: f64,
    discovered_by: String,
    melt: f64, 
    #[serde(default)]
    molar_heat: f64,
    named_by: String,
    number: String,
    period: u32,
    phase: String,
    source: String,
    spectral_img: String,
    summary: String,
    symbol: String,
    xpos: u32,
    ypos: u32,
}
```

This works fine until it gets to fields which contain a "null" value. 
E.g. for the field `"color": null,` in Helium.

The error message I get is `{ code: Message("invalid type: unit value, expected a string"), line: 8, column: 17 }` for this field.

I experimented with the `#[serde(default)]` Macro. But this only works when the field is missing in the JSON file, not when there is a `null` value.

I like to do the deserialization with the standard macros avoiding to program a Visitor Trait. Is there a trick I miss?

Comment: It is **strongly recommended** that you read [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/), which covers the concept of `Option` and `Result`, which are very pervasive in Rust.

Comment: I already did this, but a hint would be helpful how to handle this case, as it seems I need to think a little bit different than I expected. As I said above my assumption is that I need to implement the Visitor Trait and I wanted to avoid that. As I said below: I also wanted to avoid to parse all the read Structures a second time and hoped that Serde has some kind of magic to help.

Comment: Your question would be clearer if you provided a [MCVE]. As-is, you've provided code and the input, but not what *output you want*. As you can see, the ambiguity you've presented has resulted in two wildly different answers.

Comment: ok, thanks, I will do this the next time.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

A deserialization error occurs because the struct definition is incompatible with the incoming objects: the `color` field can also be `null`, as well as a string, yet giving this field the type `String` forces your program to always expect a string. This is the default behaviour, which makes sense. Be reminded that `String` (or other containers such as `Box`) are not "nullable" in Rust. As for a `null` value not triggering the default value instead, that is just how Serde works: if the object field wasn't there, it would work because you have added the default field attribute. On the other hand, a field "color" with the value `null` is not equivalent to no field at all.

One way to solve this is to adjust our application's specification to accept `null | string`, as specified by @user25064's answer:

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug, Clone)]
pub struct Element {
    color: Option<String>,
}
```

[Playground with minimal example](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=f23ff1a25fe74b54454f0169e54c23c3&version=undefined)

Another way is to write our own deserialization routine for the field, which will accept `null` and turn it to something else of type `String`. This can be done with the attribute `#[serde(deserialize_with=...)]`.

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug, Clone)]
pub struct Element {
    #[serde(deserialize_with="parse_color")]
    color: String,
}

fn parse_color<'de, D>(d: D) -> Result<String, D::Error> where D: Deserializer<'de> {
    Deserialize::deserialize(d)
        .map(|x: Option<_>| {
            x.unwrap_or("black".to_string())
        })
}
```

[Playground](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=4d0d3d751b84574a8ff56207ba01a8ae&version=undefined)

See also:

- [How can I distinguish between a deserialized field that is missing and one that is null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44331037/how-can-i-distinguish-between-a-deserialized-field-that-is-missing-and-one-that)

Comment: Thank you, especially for the explanation. I think I will go with the second way, so I can avoid a translation class (from a structure with Option<T> to the structure I like to work with)

Comment: I really wish Serde would handle this in a better way. `null` is not a valid value in Rust but *is* a valid value in a JSON, thus Serde shall just implement the basic JSON standards. The solutions at the moment are all verbose and sub-optimals. Either using Option<...> for every field (and then `unwrap_or_else` for every field, huh...), or append a `#[serde(deserialize_with="...")]` to every field, which seems actually maybe better

Answer (score 8):

Any field that can be null should be an `Option` type so that you can handle the null case. Something like this?

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug, Clone)]
pub struct Element {
    ...
    color: Option<String>,
    ...
}
```

Comment: I hoped there is some trick to automate this conversion. I wanted to avoid to parse the Element struct a second time after it came back from the Serde  parser and repair all the null values myself.

Answer (score 6):

Based on code from [here](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/1098#issuecomment-346706565), when one needs default values to be deserialized if `null` is present.

```rust
// Omitting other derives, for brevity 
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Foo {
   #[serde(deserialize_with = "deserialize_null_default")]
   value: String, 
}

fn deserialize_null_default<'de, D, T>(deserializer: D) -> Result<T, D::Error>
where
    T: Default + Deserialize<'de>,
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
{
    let opt = Option::deserialize(deserializer)?;
    Ok(opt.unwrap_or_default())
}
```

[playground link](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d1b67fae798e958b377c622fd009de14) with full example. This also works for `Vec` and `HashMap`.

Answer (score 0):

https://crates.io/crates/serde_with has a helper that can deserialize null into a default value https://docs.rs/serde_with/3.4.0/serde_with/struct.DefaultOnNull.html

```
#[serde_as]
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Element {
    #[serde_as(as = "DefaultOnNull")]
    color: Option<String>
}
```