# How to handle potentially missing fields using serde_json and the Value enum?

Tags: rust, serde

I have a data stream of JSON where some JSON objects may be missing certain fields or have fields I am unaware of in advance.

My solution is to use:

```
let v: Value = serde_json::from_str(data)?;
```

How do I handle accessing the field `stuff`? If I know it exists, I can use:

```
v["stuff"]
```

How do I handle the case `stuff` isn't a field in my data?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Accessing a missing field by the `Index` implementation of `Value` (i.e. `v["stuff"]`) will panic if the field does not exist. Instead, use [`Value::get`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/value/enum.Value.html#method.get), which returns an [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html):

```
if let Some(field) = v.get("stuff") {
    println!("field = {:?}", field);
} else {
    println!("field is missing");
}
```

Answer (score 21):

> My solution is to use [`serde_json::Value`]

I'd still use type-driven serialization, wrapping the potentially-missing field in an `Option`.

```
use serde::Deserialize; // 1.0.101
use serde_json; // 1.0.40

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Data {
    required: i32,
    missing: Option<String>,
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let data = r#"{"required": 42, "extra": true}"#;
    let data = serde_json::from_str::<Data>(data)?;
    println!("{:?}", data);

    let data = r#"{"required": 42, "extra": true, "missing": "cow"}"#;
    let data = serde_json::from_str::<Data>(data)?;
    println!("{:?}", data);

    Ok(())
}
```

```
Data { required: 42, missing: None }
Data { required: 42, missing: Some("cow") }
```

If you have fields where the name cannot be known at compile time, you can use `serde_json::Value` in addition to this solution. See [How can I use Serde's custom (de)serialization to update a subset of arbitrary input?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51002462/155423)

See also:

- [How can I deserialize an optional field with custom functions using Serde?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44301748/155423)