# How can I distinguish between a deserialized field that is missing and one that is null?

Tags: rust, serde

I'd like to use [Serde](https://serde.rs/) to parse some JSON as part of a HTTP PATCH request. Since PATCH requests don't pass the entire object, only the relevant data to update, I need the ability to tell between a value that was not passed, a value that was explicitly set to `null`, and a value that is present.

I have a value object with multiple nullable fields:

```
struct Resource {
    a: Option<i32>,
    b: Option<i32>,
    c: Option<i32>,
}
```

If the client submits JSON like this:

```
{"a": 42, "b": null}
```

I'd like to change `a` to `Some(42)`, `b` to `None`, and leave `c` unchanged.

I tried wrapping each field in one more level of `Option`:

```
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct ResourcePatch {
    a: Option<Option<i32>>,
    b: Option<Option<i32>>,
    c: Option<Option<i32>>,
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=01d650373b308a5086860c699c648228)

This does not make a distinction between `b` and `c`; both are `None` but I'd have wanted `b` to be `Some(None)`.

I'm not tied to this representation of nested `Option`s; any solution that can distinguish the 3 cases would be fine, such as one using a custom enum.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Quite likely, the only way to achieve that right now is with a custom deserialization function. Fortunately, it is not hard to implement, even to make it work for any kind of field:

```
fn deserialize_optional_field<'de, T, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Option<Option<T>>, D::Error>
where
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
    T: Deserialize<'de>,
{
    Ok(Some(Option::deserialize(deserializer)?))
}
```

Then each field would be annotated as thus:

```
#[serde(deserialize_with = "deserialize_optional_field")]
a: Option<Option<i32>>,
```

You also need to annotate the struct with `#[serde(default)]`, so that empty fields are deserialized to an *"unwrapped"* `None`. The trick is to wrap present values around `Some`.

Serialization relies on another trick: skipping serialization when the field is `None`:

```
#[serde(deserialize_with = "deserialize_optional_field")]
#[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
a: Option<Option<i32>>,
```

[Playground](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=62d611b5544077a2471ed6ad68b5ed67&version=stable) with the full example. The output:

```
Original JSON: {"a": 42, "b": null}
> Resource { a: Some(Some(42)), b: Some(None), c: None }
< {"a":42,"b":null}
```

Comment: See also [Support, or at least document the "double option" pattern](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/1042)

Comment: I'm a bit flabbergasted that even to this day we don't have a simple directive to turn off deserialization for struct item or struct within a struct. The above code was an excellent start but doesn't work for structs within structs that return empty. Many Rest APIs have different items returning null or none depending on the request. With a lot of mucking about I've implemented my own function based on the above but it shouldn't be this hard?

Answer (score 17):

Building off of [E_net4's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44331646/155423), you can also create an enum for the three possibilities:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Patch<T> {
    Missing,
    Null,
    Value(T),
}

impl<T> Default for Patch<T> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Patch::Missing
    }
}

impl<T> From<Option<T>> for Patch<T> {
    fn from(opt: Option<T>) -> Patch<T> {
        match opt {
            Some(v) => Patch::Value(v),
            None => Patch::Null,
        }
    }
}

impl<'de, T> Deserialize<'de> for Patch<T>
where
    T: Deserialize<'de>,
{
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        Option::deserialize(deserializer).map(Into::into)
    }
}
```

This can then be used as:

```
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct ResourcePatch {
    #[serde(default)]
    a: Patch<i32>,
}
```

Unfortunately, you still have to annotate each field with `#[serde(default)]` (or apply it to the entire struct). Ideally, the implementation of `Deserialize` for `Patch` would handle that completely, but I haven't figured out how to do that yet.

Comment: "Ideally, the implementation of `Deserialize` for `Patch` would handle that completely" My assumption so far is that this is impossible. From the moment that you attempt to deserialize a `Patch`, you expect the value to exist in its serialized form. On the contrary, `Patch::Missing` exists through its "non-existence" in our container (you cannot actually serialize `Patch::Missing` to JSON on its own). AFAIK a `Serialize` cannot choose not to be serialized, nor can it tell the container to skip that part of the process.

Comment: Well, actually, my previous comment is more applicable to serialization, and not deserialization. Regardless, the logic is somewhat dual: `Deserialize` cannot tell the `Deserializer` to deserialize values that it just won't find. If we have an empty object `{}`, the implementations of `Deserialize` can do nothing about it, but the deserializer can, once it knows to fill in a default.

Comment: I prefer this approach to the "double option" pattern as it gives you a more explicit and understandable type than wrapped options do- thanks! Solves https://stackoverflow.com/q/56661241/141881 for me :D

Answer (score 2):

Building up on [Shepmaster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44332837/155423) and adding serialization.

```rust
use serde::ser::Error;
use serde::{Deserialize, Deserializer};
use serde::{Serialize, Serializer};

// #region ------ JSON Absent support
// build up on top of https://stackoverflow.com/a/44332837

/// serde Valueue that can be Absent, Null, or Valueue(T)
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum Maybe<T> {
    Absent,
    Null,
    Value(T),
}

#[allow(dead_code)]
impl<T> Maybe<T> {
    pub fn is_absent(&self) -> bool {
        match &self {
            Maybe::Absent => true,
            _ => false,
        }
    }
}

impl<T> Default for Maybe<T> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Maybe::Absent
    }
}

impl<T> From<Option<T>> for Maybe<T> {
    fn from(opt: Option<T>) -> Maybe<T> {
        match opt {
            Some(v) => Maybe::Value(v),
            None => Maybe::Null,
        }
    }
}

impl<'de, T> Deserialize<'de> for Maybe<T>
where
    T: Deserialize<'de>,
{
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        Option::deserialize(deserializer).map(Into::into)
    }
}

impl<T: Serialize> Serialize for Maybe<T> {
    fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
        S: Serializer,
    {
        match self {
            // this will be serialized as null
            Maybe::Null => serializer.serialize_none(),
            Maybe::Value(v) => v.serialize(serializer),
            // should have been skipped
            Maybe::Absent => Err(Error::custom(
                r#"Maybe fields need to be annotated with: 
  #[serde(default, skip_serializing_if = "Maybe::is_Absent")]"#,
            )),
        }
    }
}
// #endregion --- JSON Absent support
```

And then you can use it this way:

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Rect {
    #[serde(default, skip_serializing_if = "Maybe::is_absent")]
    stroke: Maybe<i32>,

    w: i32,

    #[serde(default, skip_serializing_if = "Maybe::is_absent")]
    h: Maybe<i32>,
}


// .... 


let json = r#"
{
  "stroke": null,
  "w": 1
}"#;
    
let deserialized: Rect = serde_json::from_str(json).unwrap();
println!("deserialized = {:?}", deserialized);
// will output: Rect { stroke: Null, w: 1, h: Absent }

let serialized = serde_json::to_string(&deserialized).unwrap();
println!("serialized back = {}", serialized);
// will output: {"stroke":null,"w":1}
```

I wish Serde had a built-in way to handle JSON's `null` and `absent` states.

**Update 2021-03-12** - Updated to `Maybe::Absent` as it is more JSON and SQL DSL idiomatic.

The catch with this approach is that we can express:

- `type | null` with the default `Option<type>`
- `type | null | absent` with `Maybe<type>`

But we cannot express

- `type | absent`

The solution would be to refactor `Maybe` to just have `::Present(value)` and `::Absent` and support `Maybe<Option<type>>` for the `type | null | absent`. So this will give us full coverage.

- `type | null` with the default `Option<type>`
- `type | absent` with `Maybe<type>`
- `type | absent | null` with `Maybe<Option<type>>`

I am trying to implement this without adding a `#[serde(deserialize_with = "deserialize_maybe_field")]` but not sure it is possible. I might be missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1):

You can now use [double_option](https://docs.rs/serde_with/latest/serde_with/rust/double_option/index.html) from the [serde_with](https://docs.rs/serde_with/latest/serde_with/) crate, which does exactly what you want.