# How to only allow one field or the other with Serde?

Tags: rust, serde

Say I have this struct:

```rust
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct MyStruct {
    field_1: Option<usize>, // should only have field_1 or field_2
    field_2: Option<usize>, // should only have field_1 or field_2
    other_field: String,
}
```

How can I deserialize this but only allow one of these fields to exist?

Comment: Use an enum, I guess.

Comment: Are the two fields mutually exclusive? Or, are there cases where they are both present?

Comment: @Joe_Jingyu they should be mutually exclusive, I want to stop cases where they might be attempted to be both included.

Comment: If so, as @Dev611 also advised, using an `enum` instead of `struct` looks the good way to go.

Comment: I should've included in the example but there will be other fields in the `struct` also

Comment: Then, is it acceptable to replace the two fields with a field of the enum type which has field_1 and field_2 as its two variants? if not, I don't think it is possible to hide a field of a struct. Maybe you can consider the solution in the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44331037/how-can-i-distinguish-between-a-deserialized-field-that-is-missing-and-one-that) to use an enum to distinguish the tri-states: `Some(value)`, `None` and missing.

Answer (score 4):

The suggestions in the comments to use an enum are likely your best bet. You don't need to *replace* your struct with an enum, instead you'd add a separate enum type to represent this constraint, e.g.:

```
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

#[derive(Deserialize)]
enum OneOf {
    F1(usize), F2(usize)
}

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct MyStruct {
    one_of_field: OneOf,
    other_field: String,
}
```

Now `MyStruct`'s `one_of_field` can be initialized with either an `F1` or an `F2`.

Answer (score 3):

@dimo414's answer is correct about the `enum` being necessary, but the code sample will not function in the way the question is described. This is caused by a couple factors related to how `enum`s are deserialized. Mainly, **it will not enforce mutual exclusion of the two variants and will silently pick the first variant that matches** and ignore extraneous fields. Another issue is the enum will be treated as a separate structure within `MyStruct` (Ex: `{"one_of_field":{"F1":123},"other_field":"abc"}` in JSON).

### Solution

For anyone wanting an easy solution, here it is. However keep in mind that variants of the mutually exclusive type can not contain `#[serde(flatten)]` fields (more information in the issue section). To accommodate neither `field_1` or `field_2`, `Option<MutuallyExclusive>` can be used in `MyStruct`.

```rust
/// Enum containing mutually exclusive fields. Variants names will be used as the
/// names of fields unless annotated with `#[serde(rename = "field_name")]`.
#[derive(Deserialize)]
enum MutuallyExclusive {
    field_1(usize),
    field_2(usize),
}

#[derive(Deserialize)]
/// `deny_unknown_fields` is required. If not included, it will not error when both
/// `field_1` and `field_2` are both present.
#[serde(deny_unknown_fields)]
struct MyStruct {
    /// Flatten makes it so the variants of MutuallyExclusive are seen as fields of 
    /// this struct. Without it, foo would be treated as a separate struct/object held
    /// within this struct.
    #[serde(flatten)]
    foo: MutuallyExclusive,
    other_field: String,
}
```

### The Issue

**TL;DR:** *It should be fine to use `deny_unknown_fields` with `flatten` in this way so long as types used in `MutuallyExclusive` do not use `flatten`.*

If you read the `serde` documentation, you may notice it warns that using `deny_unknown_fields` in conjunction with `flatten` is unsupported. This is problematic as it throws the long-term reliability of the above code into question. As of writing this, `serde` will not produce any errors or warnings about this configuration and is able to handle it as intended.

The pull request adding this warning cited 3 issues when doing so:

- [#[serde(flatten)] error behavior is different to normal one](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/1957)
- [deny_unknown_fields incorrectly fails with flattened untagged enum](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/1600)
- [Structs with nested flattens cannot be deserialized if deny_unknown_fields is set](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/1547)

To be honest, I don't really care about the first one. I personally feel it is a bit overly pedantic. It simply states that the error message is not exactly identical between a type and a wrapper for that type using `flatten` for errors triggered by `deny_unknown_fields`. This should not have any effect on the functionality of the code above.

However, the other two errors are relevant. They both relate to nested `flatten` types within a `deny_unknown_fields` type. Technically the second issue uses `untagged` for the second layer of nesting, but it has the same effect as `flatten` in this context. The main idea is that `deny_unknown_fields` is unable to handle more than a single level of nesting without causing issues. The use case is in any way at fault, but the way `deny_unknown_fields` and `flattened` are handled makes it difficult to implement a workaround.

### Alternative

However, if anyone still feels uncomfortable with using the above code, you can use this version instead. It will be a pain to work with if there are a lot of other fields, but sidesteps the warning in the documentation.

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
#[serde(untagged, deny_unknown_fields)]
enum MyStruct {
    WithField1 {
        field_1: usize,
        other_field: String,
    },
    WithField2 {
        field_2: usize,
        other_field: String,
    },
}
```

Comment: Can you share a Rust Playground example of Serde silently picking the first matching variant?

Comment: @dimo414 this was a couple months ago so I do not have the original test cases. If I remember correctly, this situation only occurs when an input can satisfy multiple variants. Since `serde` will silently ignore fields that are not present on the destination structure (unless you use `deny_unknown_fields`) it is able to stop after successfully parsing the first variant. Generally this is helpful since it lets you ignore fields that are not relevant to your use-case, but fields that are truly mutually exclusive should produce an error if both are present at the same time.

Comment: I'm not clear why there's an issue with unknown fields in this circumstance; both variants of the enum are known to the deserializer, so I'm surprised it would consider the second variant "unknown".

Comment: @dimo414, unknown fields simply refers to fields which are unused while parsing. If it received `{"field_1":3,"field_2":4}`, then it would find `"field_2":4` to be unknown for the variant `field_1(usize)` and vice versa. Since both variants result in unused fields it is unable to satisfy `MutuallyExclusive` and an error is produced.

Comment: @dimo414, here is a [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=89035505eac98a1ee69630170fbf7a35) you can use to try different solutions. So far the solution I posted has been the best one I have found, but it is not perfect. Ideally it would enforce mutual exclusion on the two fields without requiring `deny_unknown_fields` be enforced on the entire object. I would be interested to see if you (or anyone else) finds a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can deserialize your struct and then verify that all the invariants your type should uphold. You can implement `Deserialize` for your type to this while also relying on the derive macro to do the heavy lifting.

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Deserializer};

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
#[serde(remote = "Self")]
struct MyStruct {
    field_1: Option<usize>, // should only have field_1 or field_2
    field_2: Option<usize>, // should only have field_1 or field_2
    other_field: String,
}

impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for MyStruct {
    fn deserialize<D: Deserializer<'de>>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error> {
        use serde::de::Error;
        
        let s = Self::deserialize(deserializer)?;
        if s.field_1.is_some() && s.field_2.is_some() {
            return Err(D::Error::custom("should only have field_1 or field_2"));
        }
        
        Ok(s)
    }
}

fn main() -> () {
    dbg!(serde_json::from_value::<MyStruct>(serde_json::json!({
        "field_1": 123,
        "other_field": "abc"
    })));
    dbg!(serde_json::from_value::<MyStruct>(serde_json::json!({
        "field_2": 456,
        "other_field": "abc"
    })));
    dbg!(serde_json::from_value::<MyStruct>(serde_json::json!({
        "field_1": 123,
        "field_2": 456,
        "other_field": "abc"
    })));
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a58af9fc29c396a22e7a25cf1c008bf1)