# How to deserialize Option<T> where T has a custom deserializer?

Tags: rust, deserialization, serde

I want to create deserialize function for `Option<T>` where I already have a custom deserializer for `T` and I want to use that deserializer for T, when deserializing `Option<T>`:

```rust
pub fn deserialize(deserializer: D) -> Result<T, D::Error>
{
    ...
}
```

That is `null` in JSON to be deserialized to `None` and non-null to `Some(deserialize(deserializer)?)`.

How to define:

```rust
pub fn deserialize(deserializer: D) -> Result<Option<T>, D::Error>
{
    ... // What here?
}
```

Comment: You're asking the wrong question here: If `null` should deserialize to `Option::None`, then you need a custom deserializer for `Option`, not for the `T` inside that `Option`. The provided deserialization for `Option` is agnostic towards the `T` it contains and it's deserializer, but - afaics - you want `Option` to be `None` in case `T` deserializes from `none`. But by the time your `T` sees a `null`, the `Option`-deserializer is already in the `Some`-state... You may want a custom `MyOptionIncludingNone` that has a `into_option(self) -> Option` on it.

Comment: @cdhowie No. That thread doesn't even have any functions (not counting a closure) that return `Result<Option<...>, ...>`

Comment: @user2722968 I don't quite understand you. Do you imply that `Option<u32>` cannot be deserialized as `None` from `null` in JSON? (This seems to follow from what you say.) So, need to clarify.

Comment: @user2722968 Oh, probably in my real task, `None` maps to a missing field, not to `null`.

Comment: @user2722968 I see the problem this way: I need to parse an `Option`. But what the generic argument of `Option` should be? If it is `T`, it would use the default deserializer for `T` (if it exists), not my `deserialize` function. That is, it is not what I need. Any solution?

Comment: @porton [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65705111/501250) does, as `Option<T>: Default`. You simply apply it to a field of type `Option<T>`.

Comment: @cdhowie It doesn't, because in that answer deserialization of `T` is done by default deserializer, not by my function `deserialize` as I asked in my question.

Comment: I wanted to close as unclear

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Create type `Wrap`:

```rust
struct Wrap(T);
```

Define `Deserialize` for `Wrap`.

Now I can define the `deserialize` function for `T` as deserializing `Wrap` and unwrapping the value of `T`.